# Questions about intramolecular interactions in AMBER forcefield

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, intermolecular-forces

I am trying to run a molecular dynamics simulation with AMBER forcefield. However, it's the first time I use is, and while I know the form of the various intra- and intermolecular energy terms, some details are not clear to me. So, for the AMBER forcefield:

- **What pairs are excluded in the summation of intramolecular Lennard-Jones interactions?** Typical choices are “excluding bonded atoms”, “excluding 1-2 and 1-3 pairs”, “excluding 1-2 and 1-3, applying a factor 1/2 to 1-4 pairs”, and “excluding 1-2, 1-3 and 1-4 pairs”.
- **For torsion potentials, is the potential scaled by the number of such torsions?** (as is done in the DREIDING forcefield, to ensure a constant torsional barrier for the central bond)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your first question, [this site](http://www.quimica.urv.es/~bo/MOLMOD/General/Forcefields/AMBER.html#Special) states that 1-4-interactions are scaled by a factor of 0.5, which I suppose implies 1-2 and 1-3 interactions being excluded.

The answer to your second question is yes, as can be seen [here (section TORSIONS)](http://www.scm.com/Doc/Doc2010/ADF/ADF-QMMM/page44.html). The potential is divided (and thus scaled) by N<sub>tors</sub>.